# Accessing data inside a table inside a table gives nil value

Tags: lua

As of now, I'm trying to draw a layered world map from a spritesheet, through Tiled (pretty useful since you can export the map you've created visually, directly in a .lua file).

Concerning this, I've encountered a problem: Tiled provides a lua file of this type, let's call it data.lua

```
return {
---data
tilesets = {
image = "path/to/image",
imagewidth = 2560,
imageheight = 1664,
--other data
},

layers = { 

layer1 = {}, --there's data in here
layer2 = {} --there's data in here

}

}
```

In another file, world_map.lua, i have this

```
local world_map = {}
local world_data = {}
world_data = require "data"

local last_tile = (world_data.tilesets.imagewidth *  world_data.tilesets.imageheight)/(world_data.tilewidth * world_data.tileheight)

--various functions which also use world_data

return world_map
```

now, when I run this code, I get that it's impossible to operate arithmethic operations on imagewidth because it's a nil value, so, i guess, it looks like it's not initialised. I can't understand what I'm doing wrong: the require instruction should assegnate that table (the one returned by data.lua) to the local variable and then I simply access this variable and operate on its fields. Then again, all the fields inside the nested table are initialised with their own value, but they are nil according to the interpreter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `for k,v in pairs(world_data) do print(k,v) end` give you?

Comment: The original table has a total of 10 elements, with that loop, it prints the key and the value of all the 10 elements, the table elements inside the main table give something like "tilesets table: 0x0249e5e8"

Comment: ok, if i do the same thing for world_data.tilesets, i get "1 table: 0x...",i think i've understood where's the issue

Comment: using world_data.tilesets[1]["imagewidth"] should solve the problem: is there another way to write it? I mean, without using the key 1...

Comment: From the sample you've given, using `world_data.tilesets.imagewidth` was correct. But from the output you show above, the original `data.lua` is written differently.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right and I just noticed it thanks to you: the data inside tilesets was actually inside another table inside tilesets. And from this the need to use tileset[1].imagewidth